# Oracle Database CPU, Memory utilization history

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I need to determine the workload of our database instance each week, AWR report provides many details but its very hard to break down the data.

I need a query that produces a data set that represents the snap-id with the following value:
CPU utilization
Memory Utilization
Read/Write operations

Using this set I will be able to create a histogram shows the  CPU, memory, and read/write utilization during the week by each hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try querying the `DBA_HIST_SYSMETRIC_SUMMARY` view to get the CPU utilization Memory Utilization Read/Write operations at the SNAP_ID level.

Sample query provided below:

```
select * 
from DBA_HIST_SYSMETRIC_SUMMARY
where snap_id=<snap_id>
  and metric_name in ('Host CPU Utilization (%)','I/O Megabytes per Second','I/O Requests per Second','Total PGA Allocated');
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to say that this view is submitted to Diagnostic & Tuning Pack option (chargeable).
this is the case for all views 'DBA_HIST'.